# Mask and reshape a matrix using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to use a `mask` to select vectors in `mat` variable. Below is the resultant matrix that I expcxt to get:

```
[[0, 0, 2, 2],
 [4, 4, 5, 5],
 [8, 8, 9, 9]]
```

Below is the code that I use:

```
mat = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], 
                   [[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]], 
                   [[7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]])
mask = tf.constant([[True, False, True], 
                    [True, True, False], 
                    [False, True, True]])
masked = tf.boolean_mask(mat, mask)
res = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([4])(masked)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(res.eval())
```

However, I get an error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 12 values, but the requested shape has 24
     [[{{node reshape/Reshape}}]]
```

How should I handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want reshape it then using `tf.reshape` instead, because `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` will take first dimension as batch size:

```
#TF2
import tensorflow as tf

mat = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], 
                   [[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]], 
                   [[7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]])
mask = tf.constant([[True, False, True], 
                    [True, True, False], 
                    [False, True, True]])
masked = tf.boolean_mask(mat, mask)
res = tf.reshape(masked, (-1, 4))
print(res)
```

If you want using `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` then you can do following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mat = tf.constant([[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], 
                   [[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]], 
                   [[7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9]]])
mask = tf.constant([[True, False, True], 
                    [True, True, False], 
                    [False, True, True]])
masked = tf.boolean_mask(mat, mask)
masked = tf.expand_dims(masked, axis=0)
res = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 4))(masked)
res = tf.squeeze(res, axis=0)
print(res)
```

Outputs of both:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 2 2]
 [4 4 5 5]
 [8 8 9 9]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
```